# How to configure appsettings Logging section to define provider with filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, azure-web-app-service

I want to add logging to azure blobs. I use `AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics` to logging diagnostics information into blobs.

It works fine, but some special information (business info) I want to put into another blob.

In my controller I create `ILogger` with `category == "BusinessLogger"`.

It gives me possibility to create filters for this category, but not to configure providers and filters in *appsettings* to add another `BlobLoggerProvider` with filter for category.

Is it possible out of the box, without additional code?

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddConsole();
            logging.AddDebug();
            logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            //logging.AddProvider(new BlobLoggerProvider(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection(...)));
            logging.AddFilter((provider, category, logLevel) => {
                if (provider == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices.Internal.BlobLoggerProvider")
                {
                    return category == "BusinessLogger";
                }
                return true;
            });

        })
        .UseApplicationInsights();
```